# Hibernate in multithreaded env

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, innodb

I have a webservice using Hibernate as DAL - using MySql with InnoDB.

Since I want to make webservice calls really short (for better user experience in client side) I am using 2 threads with msg queue to do some work.

1 thread gets userId in the message, loads the user from the DB and gets it email address and send email to.

Second thread is used like this:
Webservice call.... doing some actions.
Adding ActivityLog into the DB.
Doing session.save( log ); session.commit();
Now we send message to the thread with the logId.
Message received - insert new entries into timeline table (userid, logId). Session is different session object than the main logic session object.

Should I have problems in this? in lazy loading? in the threads, since message is sent to the thread after commit()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Webservice -> Message queue architecture is pretty standard in case you don't need synchronous reply to the web service.

In the web service, store whatever you want into the database and the message queue will pick that up later.

A different session is not a problem, but if you have a single static Session for each of these threads, they may be subject to Session bloat: objects piling up in the Session cache.
More on this: http://suryagaddipati.wordpress.com/2008/02/15/hibernate-rich-clients-and-long-running-sessions/

Comment: Well, I am calling the sessionFactory,getCurrentSession(). While in cfg file <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>. Am I in trouble?